# ROS cv_bridge in a class leads to segfault when cv_ptr->image is accessed

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, ros

I'm having an issue where when I get my `const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg` in my callback function, and do a `cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8);` where `cv_ptr` is a `cv_bridge::CvImagePtr`, and try to do anything with the `cv_ptr->image`, the line where I do `toCvCopy` segfaults.  When I leave the pointer alone and maybe access its contents or something elsewhere in my class, it's seemingly fine...  I'm extremely confused.

Here's some of my real code:

```
void CNNLocalizer::imageCB(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg)
{
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

  try
  {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8);

    ROS_INFO("Attempt!");
    cv::Mat image = cv_ptr->image.clone();
    ROS_INFO("Success!");

    image.convertTo(g_most_recent_image_, CV_32FC3);

    g_img_height_ = msg->height;
    g_img_width_ = msg->width;

    g_got_image_ = true;
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception &e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed converting the received message: %s", e.what());
    return;
  }
}
```

If I get rid of the business where I try to `clone` the `cv_ptr->image`, there is no segfault...  Any tips or tricks?  Am I misunderstanding how things are working here...?

Edit:  I am running my camera data through a looping rosbag with --clock enabled.

Comment: Seems to be only an issue on my home computer...  My code worked just fine on my lab computer.  Maybe some witchcraft was going on... I'll report more details if I ever find them!

Comment: Not an answer, but should probably
 - Not pass a constptr message type by reference, just use a constptr or a reference in the callback
 - Pass in the address to the toCvCopy
 - You can do `if (ptr)` to determine if it's not a `nullptr`

Years later, I'm better at C++

Answer (score 0):

try debugging that using a try/catch block for "cv_bridge::toCvCopy"

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
try
{
  cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
  ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
  return;
}
```

and add the exception description when it occurs.

A quick fix would be changing the line :

```
cv::Mat image = cv_ptr->image.clone();
```

to :

```
cv::Mat image = cv_ptr->image;
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: I don't think that would do anything as it's not throwing an exception, just segfaulting.

Comment: Also, weirdly enough, I went to my lab computer, compiled my code, and now it works fine...  Very mysterious.